# maven m2eclipse Unable to update index for nexus

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, nexus

I have a remote maven repo set up and can successfully upload artifacts and download via POMs. I also see the repo listed along with maven central in my m2eclipse global 'Maven Repositories'.

My problem is that while Maven Central is browsable and updatable in m2eclipse, my internal one is not and when it tries to update I get this:

"Unable to update index for Nexus|http://devserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/public"

Putting that url in a browser does work.

A solution is "I was able to fix it by launching the Nexus webapp and I choose repair index and rebuild index on the Public Repository Group."

but I can not rebuild the public index, and actually the index works fine for my colleague in the same office.

- nexus
       Nexus Public Mirror
       http://devserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/public
       *

Any ideas how to make m2eclipse to index properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem: it happens, i believe, when the local m2e index becomes corrupted, mainly when an Eclipse/VM crash occurs. I have found that, for my configuration, the index resides in 
  .m2/repository/.cache/m2e

I closed Eclipse, deleted all the subfolders inside that folder, and I fixed the problem.

I'm sure that it suffice to seek the file(s) where lies the index, but deleting the whole directory worked fine for me.

Ensure, before deleting, that your remote maven repo index is not corrupt (right-click repair Index in the public repository of Nexus).

Answer (score 0):

My problem resolves when i deleted .cache folder in C:\Users\Pratik.m2\repository, if all the above steps not working do try this